# Google Chrome browser - M2 admin rendering problem - lot of grey space in top of page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

We have got a problem with Google Chrome. Sometimes when we open the Magento admin page there is a lot of grey space at the top. (see attached screenprint)

I can not see any reason for this in CSS; it only happens sometimes.

It does not happen in Microsoft Edge.

Has anyone seen this issue after upgrading to the latest Google Chrome Browser version 104.0.5112.81?

[image]

Comment: This has started appearing for me too on Win and Mac with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default font size to Medium in Chrome settings (Appearance -> Font size). I had set it as Large and changing this setting fixed this issue.

Comment: Change of font size in Chrome does not help me :-(

Comment: I also disabled some of the Chrome extensions, but that alone did not fix the issue. Maybe it was a combination of disabling extensions and changing the font size. You should try disabling extensions too.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - uninstall Lastpass Google Chrome extension